# How do I filter with active data? Django

Tags: python, django, date, filter

How do I filter with active data?

Model promo have expiration (DataField)

```
def promo(request):
    promo = Promo.objects.filter( ?? )
    return render_to_response('promo.html', {'promo':promo})
```

I'm learning a lot with Django
Can someone teach me this problem?

Thank you for your attention!
Bye!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question was a bit vague but i assume you mean DateField and that you want to get all promos where expiration is later than, or today - that means all promos that havn't expired yet.

From the docs on [making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/) I suppose you can do something like this

```
Promo.objects.filter(expiration__gte=datetime.date.now())
```

and make sure you have imported datetime.

**note:**

This all depends on how you see an expiration as. If the date is today, has the promo expired? in that case use epiration_gt instead of expiration_gte.